# Plot Graph Using Plot.Js

Tags: javascript, html, plot

I having trouble trying tot plot graph using plot.js.
I followed the instruction from youtuber video. But doesn't seems to work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdC9oVwsEpk

Please helps

```js
var mydata= new Array(1,2,4,8,16,32);
var myplot = new MakeDraw();
myplot.id="qi_chart";
myplot.plotColor = 'rga(200,230,50,1)';
myplot.fsize = 15;
myplot.data = mydata;
myplot.plot()
```

```html
<canvas id="qi_chart" width="800" height="300"></canvas>
<script src="plot.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an absolute link to the plot.js source. Using the link from the video you posted works fine:

```js
var mydata= new Array(1,2,4,8,16,32);
var myplot = new MakeDraw();
myplot.id="qi_chart";
myplot.plotColor = 'rga(200,230,50,1)';
myplot.fsize = 15;
myplot.data = mydata;
myplot.plot()
```

```html
<canvas id="qi_chart" width="800" height="300"></canvas>
<script src="http://mathmed.blox.pl/resource/plot.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Brandon - there is an error stated that MakeDraw is not defined.

Comment: Hi Mark. The reason you see the error "MakeDraw is not defined" is because MakeDraw is defined in plot.js and your code does not know where to find plot.js. You have to point it to the plot.js hosted at mathmed.blox.pl. Just change the last line of your code to the last line of my code and it will fix the error.

Comment: Thank you, i did change the path like urs but still get undefined. Therefore i change to google chart instead and manage to get it to work.